# Display products related to custom taxonomies

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a online shop project. I this i created a post type i.e Products and taxonomy products_categories Men Wearing, Women wearing and kids etc. In sidebar i created a widget and display all the custom taxonomies. Now i want to display all products related to that particular category. So when i click on any category suppose men then my url looks like "htp://mydomain/mysite/product_categories/kids-clothing/". I created a taxonomy.php but still 404.php is running. Can somebody tell me whats wrong in ht code.

```
'
<?php
   $taxonomy     = 'product_categories';
   $orderby      = 'name';
   $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
   $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
   $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
   $title        = '';
   $empty        = 0;

   $args = array(
     'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
     'orderby'      => $orderby,
     'show_count'   => $show_count,
     'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
     'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
     'title_li'     => $title,
     'hide_empty'   => $empty
   );

   ?>
   <h4 class="title1">Show By Category</h4>
   <ul id="list">
   <?php 
     wp_list_categories( $args );
   ?>
   </ul>'
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think taxonomy.php is a core file so why you need to create this? Second thing you only want to create custom taxonomy. right?

Comment: Is your taxonomy.php is in right folder. The code above does not have term for taxonomy. Terms are like kids-clothing, Men wearing etc. Where you passing terms? --- to display products from custom post type use ---- `query_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'products',
            'showposts' => '10',
            'product_categories' => 'kids-clothing',
            
        ));`

Comment: Ali Exalter still i just want to run my taxonomy.php file. i also checked it is in right folder.

Comment: finally i got the answer. Everything was fine. I just worked with setting->permalinks click default and then save change and again click on post name and save change. Now my taxonomy.php is running properly.